# Is there any framework like RoR on Python 3000?

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, frameworks, python-3.x

One of the feature I like in RoR is the db management, it can hide all the sql statement, also, it is very easy to change different db in RoR, is there any similar framework in Python 3000?

Comment: Related question: web frameworks in Python 3.x http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373945/what-web-development-frameworks-support-python-3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer was awfully outdated. The current state of afairs is:

- [Django is close to supporting Python 3](https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2012/mar/13/py3k/)
- [CherryPy](http://www.cherrypy.org/) [supports Python 3 since version 3.2](http://www.cherrypy.org/wiki/WhatsNewIn32)
- [Pyramid](http://www.pylonsproject.org/) has [Python 3 support since 1.3](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.3-branch/whatsnew-1.3.html)
- [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/), which is a lightweight WSGI micro web-framework, supports Python 3

I'm sure this list will keep growing every coming month, specially considering that [there will never be a Python 2.8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0404/).

2.7 will be the end of the line for Python 2 development, and now the official upgrade path from 2.7 is Python 3.x. I'm sure that with this state of affairs, Python 3 support from web frameworks is only going to get better and better.

---

<sub>[OUTDATED]</sub>
Python 3 is not yet in high deployment. It's still lacking a lot of third party libraries.

The recommended Python version is 2.6.x, as it's the most current, it's backwards compatible, and has many backported features from 3.1.

For Python 2.6 you will find quite a few frameworks:

- [Django](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Django)
- [Turbogears](http://www.turbogears.org/)
- [CherryPy](http://wiki.python.org/moin/CherryPy)
- [Zope](http://www.zope.org/)
- [and many more](http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks)

Comment: Actually, I use Arch Linux and it seems that it hasen't been updated, *yet* http://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/i686/python/

Answer (score 2):

I believe CherryPy is on the verge of being released for Python 3.X.

Answer (score 1):

Python 3 isn't ready for web applications right now. The WSGI 1.0 specification isn't suitable for Py3k and the related standard libraries are 2to3 hacks that don't work consistently faced with bytes vs. unicode. It's a real mess.

WEB-SIG are bashing out proposals for a WSGI revision; hopefully it can move forward soon, because although Python 3 isn't mainstream yet it's certainly heading that way, and the brokenness of webdev is rather embarrassing.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 is not ready for practical use, because there is not yet enough libraries that have been updated to support Python 3. So the answer is: No.

But there are LOADS of them on Python 2. Tens, at least.

Django, Turbogears, BFG and of course the old man of the game: Zope. To tell which is best for you, you need to expand your requirements a lot.

Comment: Here is a (probably not complete) list:
http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks

Answer (score -1):

There's Django but [it works with Python 2.3+ only for now](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/install/#can-i-use-django-with-python-3-0).